# UILocalNotification issue in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have used `UILocalNotification` in my code after getting the response from server. I'm sending multiple images to the server , when the response comes **1** it should show a local notification in an app.

I have tried some code it shows a notification in banner style but not one the app screen , when i press **command+shift+H**  it goes to home screen of simulator and shows the notification there instead of in app screen.

How we can show same notification on the home screen of app. I have tested this on real device but its not showing there.

My Code is:

```
 UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = res;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Image Sent";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

 if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
```

It shows like this,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle it by yourself. When local notification comes, you can use `UIAlertController` to show the payload dictionary data associated with that local notification. Inside below method, you can do it. In notification settings, change notification style to alert from banner if needed.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Comment: When i run my app in simulator it shows notification in my notification area but when i run it on real device it shows nothing. @Maulik Bhuptani

Comment: Have you tried implementing above method and is it getting called on both device & simulator?

Answer (score 0):

This method is called when notification fire in foreground for `iOS 10`:

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}
```

here you can handle the local notification and show the alert UI using `TSMessage` class https://github.com/KrauseFx/TSMessages

Comment: I have to write this method in App delegate .m file or where i'm having code for local notification. @Saurabh Jain

Comment: Yes, you have to write this in AppDelegate.m @Oneeb

Comment: It is showing again in home screen of the simulator , i want it to show on the app screen. @SaurabhJain

Comment: show the TSMessage on app screen, [TSMessage showNotificationWithTitle:@"Your Title"
                                subtitle:@"A description"
                                    type:TSMessageNotificationTypeSuccess]; @Oneeb

Comment: how we can set this TSMessage on the response? @Saurabh Jain

Answer (score 0):

Local notifications and remote notifications are ways to inform users when new data becomes available for your app, even when your app is not running in the foreground. It is your responsibility to inform user when notification is arrived.

Use [OTNotification](https://github.com/OpenFibers/OTNotification) for display Notification like push notifications' cube animation With covering statusBar While your app is in foreground.

[image]

You can Use Like this.

```
OTNotificationManager *notificationManager = [OTNotificationManager defaultManager];
OTNotificationMessage *notificationMessage = [[OTNotificationMessage alloc] init];
notificationMessage.title = [self notificationTitle];
notificationMessage.message = @"A notification. Touch me to hide me.";
[notificationManager postNotificationMessage:notificationMessage];
```

Comment: I want to show the notification after my response from server, can it be shown when user is using the app? @Harshal Shah

Comment: Yes, It is custom notification that you can display anytime in app while you are using app.

Comment: How i can fire the notification on my response? @Harshal Shah

Comment: Already send code Please check. Also you can check https://github.com/OpenFibers/OTNotification

Comment: the link u provided is missing some files i have used it in my project it is missing some of its files. @Harshal Shah

Comment: Have you checked demo? Here working fine. Send error if you have any

Comment: If you found error "Lexical or Preprocessor issue", Then comment this line. It's working fine.

Comment: There are some parse issue some of type is giving issues, like - (void)postNotificationView:(UIView/*<OTNotificationViewProtocol>*/ *)view; in this line. I have used QuartzCore frame work and copied the OTNotification folder and used the provided code but it shows issue. @Harshal Shah

Comment: When we run the project of OTNotification it runs fine but when i followed there process to copied the folder in our project and run the app it gives issues of some types , how i can remove the issues? @Harshal Shah

Comment: I can't get your issue properly, Please describe in details. what type of parse issue are you getting?